# What is a less cumbersome way to say "acknowledging of hard work"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to convey in a concise phrase the concept that the management at a company frequently gives praise to its workers for job that are well done.

Comment: +1 Good question. I feel there must be a good word for this concept, but I'm momentarily stumped.

Comment: If Alfie Kohn and Joel Spolsky [are to be believed](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000070.html), the term is *bad management*. (^_^)

Comment: @RegDwight: There is a difference between incentive awards and praise for work well done. I personally won't get out of bed for an incentive award, but I do like when someone (managerial or otherwise) sees my work and says "dude, that's awesome!"

Comment: How about "suitably appreciative"?

Comment: Are you looking for a verb phrase (e.g. recognize their work), a noun (e.g. commendation), or what they might actually say when doing it (e.g. woot)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the word [kudos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kudos).

Answer (score 3):

Recognize their contributions?
Commend their good work?
Praise their efforts?

I'm not sure how concise one can make this.

Answer (score 3):

We used to have the informal notion of an ["attaboy"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attaboy) as a verbal or written acknowledgement of work well done.

Answer (score 3):

**“(To give) credit where credit is due”** is a fairly well established idiom, close to what you’re asking for, and used sometimes in management contexts:

> A fair man, he liked to give credit where credit was due. [[Source](http://books.google.com/books?id=K6CZAAAAIAAJ&q=%22give+credit+where+credit%22&dq=%22give+credit+where+credit%22&hl=en&ei=E27eTZONHcjVsgaw6fTLBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CG4Q6AEwAQ)]

> It is not difficult to get executives to give credit where credit is due — provided that is basically the desire of top management.  [[Source](http://books.google.com/books?id=RmcNAQAAIAAJ&q=%22credit+where+credit%22+management&dq=%22credit+where+credit%22+management&hl=en&ei=oG7eTbaeBsTGswa6kvy-BQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CEkQ6AEwAA)]

Answer (score 2):

we used to say [Bravo Zulu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bravo_Zulu) for a job well done

> Bravo Zulu is a naval signal, conveyed
>   by flaghoist or voice radio, meaning
>   "Well Done"; it has also been used as
>   part of vernacular slang

Answer (score 2):

How about "recognition"

As in "The company gave the workers who had jobs well done recognition"

Answer (score 1):

If internet slang is acceptable then you could use, "Woot!". However, this term might be limited to acknowledgement where excitement is involved or an extravagant accomplishment.

```
Employee: "I just finished the 1st quarter report 2 days early"
Manager: "Woot!"
```

If you want to make it personal to where employees can really relate or understand its meaning then using a term frequently used by employees might be a better option. I worked for a small company where we used the term, "boolz" which makes no sense to anyone but us. Whe used it to acknowledge something important, exciting, or of quality, or to acknowledge one's hard earned accomplishment(s).

Comment: A similar internet (or rather, online gaming) slang term might be "Gratz", which is the gamers' short form of "Congratulations (on your victory)".

Answer (score 1):

*Magnanimous* would seem a good fit as an adjective for the management.

Answer (score 0):

A simple (1) would do:

> 1. Job well done!
> 2. Great Work!
> 3. Hails

Answer (score 0):

> I’m trying to convey in a concise phrase the concept that the management at a company frequently gives praise to its workers for job that are well done.

Based on the understanding that you are exemplifying a “company” by the way it recognizes the efforts of its employees, you can say simply that Company X is exemplary. It’s showing of appreciation to its (choose your own adjective: (*loyal, hard working, productive, creative, silently suffering*) employees.